# React Nested map/forEach wont work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am working on a CMS system with nested sub menus that are different depending on user / customization ,etc.

Trying to solve this problem I am placing a map function inside of a react component. As per documentation this approach works with only one nested map fucntion, but apparently not a second one, which is what I need to render sub menus, any ideas?

```
render() {
    return (
        <div className="ui dropdown item">
            {this.state.text}
            <i className="dropdown icon"></i>
            <div className="menu">
                {multipleOptions.split(',').map(function(option, i){
                    option.split('@').map(function(subOption, i){
                        return <a className="item" key={i + "random"}>{subOption}</a>;
                    })
                })}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: are you rendering the childrens in your component?

Comment: by your comment I suppose this approach should be working? Dont know what you mean by rendering the childrens in my component, this is inside my render component

Answer (score 5):

You need to add `return` inside first `.map`

```
{multipleOptions.split(',').map(function(option, i) {
   return option.split('@').map(function(subOption, i) {
     return <a className="item" key={i + "random"}>{ subOption }</a>;
   })
})}
```

Answer (score 2):

@AlexanderT.'s answer is correct. It reads a little nicer if you use arraow functions too

```
{multipleOptions.split(',').map((option, i)=>
   option.split('@').map((subOption, i)=>
     <a className="item" key={i + "random"}>{subOption}</a>))}
```