# React mapping multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Sorry for any confusion. To put simply I want to make several titles with unordered lists.

```
<h3>level_3 key title</h3>
<ul>
  <li>level_4 value</li>
  <li>level_4 value</li>
</ul>

<h3> another level_3 key title</h3>
<ul>
  <li>level_4 value</li>
  <li>level_4 value</li>
</ul>
```

Difficult to phrase the problem into a question. Essentially having a really hard time trying to parse through some JSON and display the data correctly. What I would like to do is display `level_3.x` *below* as a top level list item and the nested `level_4.x` as nested list items. To be clear using React

Example:

- KEY from `level_3.1`

  - String from `level_4.1`
  - String from `level_4.2`

**Repeat for every `level_3.x` object**

**Example Data**

```
"level_1":{
  "level_2.1":{
    "level_3.1":{
     "level_4.1":["string","string","string"],
     "level_4.2":["string","string","string"]
    }
    "level_3.2":{
     "level_4.1":["string","string","string"],
     "level_4.2":["string","string","string"]
    }
  }
  "level_2.2":{
     "level_3.1":{
       ... Same as above
    }
     "level_3.2":{
       ... Same as above
    }
  }
}
```

What I have done since you can only map an array, from my understanding, is try and go through `level_3.x` and push those to an Array. I can map over that and display the items as expected.

**Parent Component**

```
render(){
  return( <Child heading="A" data={resource.data} /> )
}
```

**Child Component**

```
render(){
  let groupObj;
  let groupArray;
  let subListItems;

  if('value' in this.props.data){
    var i;
    for(i = 0; i < Object.keys(groupObj).length; i++){
      groupArray.push(Object.keys(groupObj)[i] + "," + Object.values(groupObj)[i]) 
// Have removed the Object.values because I was trying to make everything flat and pull out the first item. Leaving it in because that was my original direction in the case it was actually the right way to go
    }
  }
  listItems = groupArray.map((item, index)=>(<li key={index}>{item}</li>));

  return({listItems})
}
```

Thus far I can produce:

- `level_3.1`
- `level_3.2`

`console log > [level_3.1,level_3.2]`

Which is great, and halfway there. Now where things break down is I can't seem to figure out how to get the `level_4.x` elements to render.

I tried writing another map function inside the previous:

```
listItems = groupArray.map((item, index) => (
   <li key={index}>
     {item}
     <ul>
       {subListItems = groupObj.item.map((subItem, index) => ( 
         <li key={index+1}>{subItem}</li>
       ))};
     </ul>
   </li>
 ));
```

This returns a map of undefined error, however if `item` is replaced with a key it'll work. `groupObj.level_4.1.map()` That will return a `level_4.1` values:

- level_3.1

  - level_4.1 value
  - level_4.1 value << unable to map level_4.2 and using `item` from the parent map function will return undefined

So either doing this completely wrong, or missing a way to pass in a dynamic value into that `groupObj.[needs to be dynamic based on parent].map()`

*Note, do know that using `index` as a key value is an anti-pattern just have that in for sake of getting this to work.*

**Update**

Feel like this is 90% there but having one last issue. Took both answers into consideration and the easiest for me to implement and understand what I'm typing at this time is the following:

```
render(){

  let listItems;
  let name = this.props.heading

  if('level_2' in this.props.data){

    let data = this.props.data.level_2[name];
    console.log('ok we can get to work', data); // <<< Good

    listItems = Object.keys(data).map((propKey) => (
      <ul key={propKey}>
       {propKey} // <<< Good
       {console.log('PROP KEY', propKey)} // <<< Good
         {data[propKey].map((childPropKey) =>{
           <li key={childPropKey}>
             {childPropKey} // <<<<<< PROBLEM, This returns nothing in the DOM
             {console.log(childPropKey)} // <<< Good
           </li>
         })}
     </ul>
   ));

return(<div>{listItems}</div>)
}
```

So I'm able to `console.log(childPropKey)` and return expected results. But just trying to return `{childPropKey}` nothing gets returned

**Working ES5**

```
listItems = Object.keys(data).map(function(propKey){
    return <ul key={propKey}>
      {propKey}
        {data[propKey].map(function(childPropKey){
          return <li key={childPropKey}>
            {childPropKey}
          </li>
        })}
    </ul>
  });
```

**Working ES6**

```
listItems = Object.keys(data).map((propKey) => (
  <ul key={propKey}>
    {propKey}
    {data[propKey].map((childPropKey) =>(
      <li key={childPropKey}>
        {childPropKey}                 
      </li>
     ))}
  </ul>
));
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion little flustered trying to figure this out. The goal is to show `level_3` elements as titles and the `level_4` as lists, put most simply

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of trying to convert the object into an array, just cut that out and loop directly through the Object.keys array.

```
render () (
  <ul>
    {Object.keys(this.props.data).map((propKey) => {
      <li key={propKey}>
        {this.props.data[propKey]}

        <ul>            
          {Object.keys(this.props.data[propKey]).map((childPropKey) => {
            <li key={childPropKey}>
              {this.props.data[propKey][childPropKey]}
            </li>
          })}
        </ul>
      </li>
    })}
  </ul>
);
```

I've made some assumptions on your data structure, so hopefully you can translate it to your implementation.

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Made an update to my question feel like I'm really close. Decided to go with your answer because it was the easiest for me to understand and implement at this time. There is one snag though. I can `console.log` the `childPropKey`, but unable to display anything in the DOM. You can see in the update that everything is looking good. However, the DOM is blank. Where I'm confused is if I can `console.log` results why wouldn't they display?

Comment: In your update, you are never returning anything from the function given to data[propKey].map. Also, keep in mind that the keys need to be unique, so your array of "string", "string", "string" won't work with React unless they are unique.

Comment: The keys are unique in that all the strings are different and no errors in React at the moment. `"string", "string"` is just illustrated dummy content for what I'm working with. It isn't ideal but can be remedied in a bit that's why I wasn't focused on it for the sake of getting it to work. I've added the `return()` statement. Should have mentioned that the `{propKey}` returns to the DOM just fine where I put `<ul key={propKey}> {propKey} // <<< Good ...` meant everything is working as expected. The issue is that `childPropKey` console.logs fine but doesn't render.

Comment: Got it, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37716645/react-nested-map-foreach-wont-work

For some reason can't get that to work with the Fat Arrow functions though.

Answer (score 4):

You should consider recursion for this kind of problems as it is well suited for tree traversal.

Most people ain't aware that you can treat React components as functions and use them recursively. In order to render different types of nodes, you can use the ternary operator, switch statement or other control flow mechanisms.

To iterate an `Object` you can use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to get a list of key-value pairs, which you can then process with regular `map`.

Please see the following example:

```js
const isLeaf = data => typeof data === 'string'
const isArray = data => Array.isArray(data)

const Tree = ({ data }) =>
  // render a leaf - just a string
  isLeaf(data) ? <li>{data}</li> : 

  // render an array
  isArray(data) ? 
  <ul>
    {data.map(x => <Tree data={x} />)}
  </ul> : 

  // render a tree (an object)
  <ol>
  {
    Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) =>
      <li>
        <h1>{key}</h1>
        <Tree data={value} />
      </li>
    )
  }
  </ol>

const data = {
  "level_1":{
    "level_2.1":{
      "level_3.1":{
       "level_4.1":["a","b","c"],
       "level_4.2":["string","string","string"]
      },
      "level_3.2":{
       "level_4.1":["string","e","string"],
       "level_4.2":["d","string","f"]
      }
    },
    "level_2.2":{
      "level_3.1":{
       "level_4.1":["string","string","string"],
       "level_4.2":["string","string","string"]
      },
      "level_3.2":{
       "level_4.1":["string","string","string"],
       "level_4.2":["string","string","string"]
      }
    }
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Tree data={data} />,
  document.getElementById('app')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this answer, really appreciate the time, effort, and explanation. For the sake of my understanding of what I'm writing and implementing decided to use the other answer. Although this is probably the more correct approach I didn't quite fully grasp it and will need more time, then what I have right now, to understand.