# React Nested Map and Filter with conditional render does not work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter, react-hooks, map-function

I spent so much time on fixing this issue, i decided to ask people for help.

so basically what i am trying is to render a component.
but before rendering i have 2 arrays`(labels, notes)`.
and using one of them(labels), i used map function and inside that i used filter function to get only element i want to pass to the component that is rendered.

I think there are some posts similar to this, but slightly different.
and some answers said, "when there is nested map function, the inner map needs to be wrap with tag like fragment" but what i found in other posts did not wrap it...
If anyone could help me clearing my confusion, would you please tell me if it is necessary or not.
[Cannot Render Nested Maps In ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57742802/cannot-render-nested-maps-in-reactjs) <- says wrap with tag
[React Nested map/forEach wont work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37716645/react-nested-map-foreach-wont-work) <- does not use tag

here is my code.

```
let notes = [
    {id:1, position:3, content: "apple"},
    {id:2, position:2, content: "banana"},
    {id:3, position:0, content: "orange"},
]
const labels = ["Discussion questions", "Quotes", "Sensory Ques", "Songs"];
```

```
const renderNotes = (notes) => {
    return labels.map(label => {
        console.log("---" + label + "---")
        return (
            notes.filter(note => {
            // console.log(positionLabels[note.position] + " - " + label);
            if (positionLabels[note.position] === label) {
                console.log("BINGO");
                return (
                    <CustomComponent
                        key={note.id}
                        content={note.content}
                    />
                )
            }
            })
        )
    })
}
```

and inside the return i am calling this function like below

```
{
    renderNotes(notes) 
}
```

when i was testing some like this

```
const renderNotes = (notes) => {
    return positionLabels.map(label => {
      return <div>
        {
          notes.filter(note => {
            return (
              <div>
                TEST
              </div>
            )
          })
        }
      </div>
    })
  }
```

it did not even work,
I have no idea what the error of `objects are not valid as a react child` is talking about.

Comment: It's not clear (to me, anyway) from your question what output you are actually trying to achieve. The error about objects as a child is because your `renderNotes` does not return an array of React elements or components, but an array of arrays, each of which is a subarray of `notes` (and therefore contains plain JS objects). But you're doing something very wrong anyway, because the callback you pass to `filter` appears to return a React node, when that callback only needs to return `true` or `false` (it's just for determining which elements to keep in your filter).

Answer (score 0):

First do filter then map it. Try like below

```
const renderNotes = (notes) => {
    return labels.map(label => {
        console.log("---" + label + "---")
        return (
            notes.filter(note => positionLabels[note.position] === label).map((value)=> {
                console.log("BINGO");
                return (
                    <CustomComponent
                        key={value.id}
                        content={value.content}
                    />
                )
            })
        )
    })
 }
```